# sqoop importing mysql issue

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am  4 days old with Hadoop, I am trying to import a table from my local database mysql, to learbn sqoop, my machine is ubuntu 13.04, my sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.7.0, mysql:5.5.34
this is the command I use in the prompt:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.52.60:3306/saloni --username user --table pv --password xxxx;
```

that what i get:

```
    14/06/03 16:11:36 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/06/03 16:11:36 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/06/03 16:11:36 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.7.0
14/06/03 16:11:36 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
14/06/03 16:11:36 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
14/06/03 16:11:36 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/06/03 16:11:36 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/06/03 16:11:36 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
14/06/03 16:11:37 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:827)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:686)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:709)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:347)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1298)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1110)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:506)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connessione rifiutata
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
    ... 32 more
14/06/03 16:11:37 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1116)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:506)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
```

if I use this command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saloni  --username user --password 123456 --table pv
```

it starts, but then it stucks into:

```
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

So I do not understand what my error is, can you put  me in right way?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your JDBC parameters as the link is failing to establish. Here is something I use, that works:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:<UserName>/<Password>#@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<HOST>)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<service>)))"
```

In your case, if you are using a mySQL database, you will want to use the mysql JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.52.60:3306/saloni --username user --table pv --password xxxx --target-dir '/myimport' -m 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should continue using localhost:3306. Your actual IP is not used to loopback. 8032 is the port for Yarn. I suspect you may not have configured it properly. Check the parameters below in your yarn-site.XML

```
<property><name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name> <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value> </property> <property> <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name> <value>127.0.0.1:8030</value> </property> <property> <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name> <value>127.0.0.1:8031</value> </property>
```